# Beginners Guide to Cartan for Beginners

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am working through parts of Cartan For Beginners by Ivey and Landsberg. Thankfully some exercises have solutions, but, we would benefit from some additional guidance.

> Question: I am seeking further exposition of the material in Chapter 4 or 5 of the text. I have prolonged some tableaus, but, I have doubts and would like some additional examples. Can anyone point me to some such exposition on explicit PDEs and Tableaus ?

Let me sketch the goal of the project as it might give insight into which resources we should seek. We have spent some time studying calculus over an associative real algebra. In short, when a function is $\mathcal{A}$-differentiable it must satisfy the $n^2-n$ generalized Cauchy Riemann equations, but, on the level of the algebra variables it's just calculus. On the other hand, we wonder, when can we take a given PDE or system of PDEs and gain insight into the solutions of the system by studying it in terms of the $\mathcal{A}$-calculus. For a basic example, obviously $\mathbb{C}$-variables gives insight into the solutions of Laplace's equation on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My naive hope was that the machine in Cartan for Beginners could be put to work in ciphering whether a given system of PDEs was compatible with an $\mathcal{A}$-calculus substitution. I hoped there was some natural way to use the Tableaus to judge compatibility. Maybe the hope is misguided.

**Added:** $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{R}^n$ paired with an associative multiplication over $\mathbb{R}$. To say $f: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ is $\mathcal{A}$-differentiable is to say $J_f$ is in the left-regular (matrix) representation. This is equivalent to insisting the algebra multiplication factors out of the differential; $df(v \star w) = df \star w$. For example, $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{R} \oplus j \mathbb{R}$ with $j^2=1$ gives
$$ J_f = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ b & a \end{array}\right]$$ 
I have a list of examples in:
http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-9332-7_8
and to get a better idea of the PDE idea, see:
[is this a known method for solving PDEs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143924/is-this-a-known-method-for-solving-pdes)
which illustrates the idea.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to define what you mean by $\mathcal{A}$-calculus.  Without knowing this, we can't help you.

Comment: @RobertBryant thanks for the note, I have added some detail. I suppose $\mathcal{A}$-calculus has been known by various names, I'm not sure what the best name is.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @DeaneYang The question is succinctly: does anyone have additional examples which add further insight into the Tableau method given in Chapters 4 and 5 of Cartan for Beginners.

Comment: Your question is still too vague. A tableau is essentially a way to represent a constant coefficient first order system of PDE's. So any arbitrary system of first order PDE's gives you an example of a tableau. You can then test whether the tableau is in involution or not and prolong if necessary. You need to say more about what you're hoping to learn about in the examples.

Comment: There are other approaches to this theory. A modern cohomological approach was developed by Spencer, Quillen, Guillemin, Sternberg, and Goldschmidt. A nice description of an involutive first order differential operator was given by Guillemin and is now known as Guillemin normal form. Using this description, it is easy to construct examples of involutive systems of PDE's. Still another approach, using only basic linear algebra, is described in the first chapter of my thesis, "Involutive hyperbolic differential systems", Memoirs of the AMS.

Comment: @DeaneYang Thanks for the comments, they are helpful. What I am trying to ascertain, is, if I am given a system of PDEs, let's say $n$ real PDEs in $n$ real variables, then does that system permit a reformulation as a single ODE over the algebra. Because the algebra solutions imply the general CR-equations ($n^2-n$ PDEs) I thought there would be a way to detect if the CR-equations were inconsistent with the given PDEs hence suggesting there is no natural algebra ODE which represents the given system of PDEs. I'm sorry if this is still vague, I am not in principle tied to using Tableaus...

Comment: so if there is a different way in terms of things in your thesis I am interested.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook:  I have been out of touch since Dec 19, so I didn't see the discussion until now.  In fact, your question has a reasonable answer, but it's liable to be disappointing.  Given a finite dimensional, associative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, you are asking for the smooth functions $f:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}$ that satisfy $$Df(a)(bc) = (Df(a)(b))c$$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathcal{A}$.  The obvious examples are $f(a) = pa+q$ for $p,q\in\mathcal{A}$ (since, in this case, $Df(a)(b) = pb$), and the question is whether there are any more and how many.  You want to answer this by EDS.

Comment: (cont.) One obvious case in which there are lots of such functions is when $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative, for, in this case, any convergent power series $f(x)=f_0 + f_1 (x-a) + \tfrac12\, f_2\, (x-a)^2 + \cdots$ will satisfy the above condition (here, $f_i\in\mathcal{A}$, or, more precisely, the left multiplication operators $L_{f_i}$, must go to zero fast enough to make the series converge on some neighborhood of $a\in\mathcal{A}$). However, for most non-commutative  algebras $\mathcal{A}$, this won't work, and, in fact, the affine-linear functions listed above are the only solutions.  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.)  To see this, you just need to compute the first prolongation of the tableau $$\Lambda = \{ L_a:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}\ \mid \ a\in \mathcal{A}\ \}.$$  Now, it is easy to show that an element $B$ of the first prolongation $$\Lambda^{(1)}=\Lambda\otimes\mathcal{A}^\ast\cap \mathcal{A}\otimes S^2(\mathcal{A}^\ast)$$  must be of the form $$B(a,b) = cab$$ where $c\in\mathcal{A}$ must satisfy $c(ab-ba)=0$ for all $a,b\in\mathcal{A}$.  (Just apply the definition.)  Thus, if the left-annihilator of the commutator ideal in $\mathcal{A}$ is trivial, we have $\Lambda^{(1)} = 0$. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.)  Since, for most $\mathcal{A}$, the left-annihilator of the commutator ideal is trivial, it follows that, for most $\mathcal{A}$, the only functions of the kind you want are the affine linear ones.  However, you can construct many algebras $\mathcal{A}$ for which this space isn't zero, and these will have higher order functions of the kind you want.

Comment: @RobertBryant I'm curious to know exactly what kind of higher order functions you can make $\mathcal{A}$-differentiable (in a properly constructed algebra). Specifically, I'd like to know if there are non-commutative algebras where any convergent power series is $\mathcal{A}$-differentiable, or is that only possible in the commutative case? If not, what can we say about power series $\mathcal{A}$-differentiability$ in terms of the structure of the left-annihilator of the commutator ideal?

Comment: @Sintrastes:  It has been a while since I thought about this, but, if I remember correctly, the answer is that every $\mathcal{A}$-differentiable function in a neighborhood of $a\in\mathcal{A}$ has a Taylor series expansion of the form $$ f(x) = f_0 + f_1(x-a) + f_2(x-a)^2 + \cdots$$ where the $f_i$ for $i>1$ lie in the left-annihilator of the commutator ideal.  Conversely, if $f_i$ are chosen to lie in this ideal and the above series converges, this defines an $\mathcal{A}$-differentiable function in a neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following may help: Fueter tried to describe quaternionic analysis in the sense of $\mathcal A$-Analysis in the 20's or 30's, but only first order quaternionic polynomials were possible.
The working generalization is hypercomplex Analysis or Clifford Analysis, where one generalizes the Laplacian from complex Analysis to more general algebras. I enclose references to two papers below. 
(I am not a specialist in this, I just listened to some talks during the years.)

- MR0822855 (87f:30102) Reviewed 
  Bureš, J.(CS-CHRL); Souček, V.
  Generalized hypercomplex analysis and its integral formulas. 
  Complex Variables Theory Appl. 5 (1985), no. 1, 53–70.
- MR3277680 Prelim Brackx, F.; Schepper, H. De; Eelbode, D.; Lávička, R.; Souček, V.; Fundaments of Quaternionic Clifford Analysis I: Quaternionic Structure. Adv. Appl. Clifford Algebr. 24 (2014), no. 4, 955–980.

Comment: Thank you for the references. However, I'm mostly focused on the commutative case and I'm currently trying to collect results which apply for all associative algebras over $\mathbb{R}$. Clifford Analysis would be a specialization (granted an interesting one). Sorry my question was not more focused, perhaps I will write a better one in a few weeks.